# UWP, navigation from subframe

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a problem since a few days I can get rid of. I'm trying to navigate from a subframe to another frame, the thing is, I think I actually navigate to it because the c# code is executed but the content of the frame (Textblock etc) are not loaded ...

Here is my code

Main Frame:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Grid.Row="1" 
   ItemClick="listView_ItemClickEvent">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
               <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Padding="10 5">
                   <TextBlock FontSize="20" Padding="0 5 0 0" Text="{Binding 
                       ProjCode}" Foreground="Black"/>
                   <TextBlock Padding="10 5 0 5" Text="{Binding Nome}" 
                      Foreground="#636567" />
               </StackPanel>
               <TextBlock Name="lblID" Visibility="Collapsed" 
                   Text="{Binding id}"/>                             
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <Frame Name="DetailsFrame"  Foreground="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="1"  
                   BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" Height="5000">
        <Frame.ContentTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection />
        </Frame.ContentTransitions>
    </Frame>
```

Clicking on the list a frame "ProjectDetails" is loaded on the frame "DetailsFrame". this contains another listview:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
        <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid BorderBrush="Gray">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   ***
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   ***
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Descrizione}"/>
                <TextBlock />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TempoTotale}"/>


            <TextBlock Name="lblID" Text="{Binding ID}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

From this frame (ProjectDetails) when I click on the list I need to change this frame with another one which is called "TaskDetails" ... for this task I used this code, but as I said before, the actual c# code wrote on the TaskDetail page is executed but the interface like Ttextblock etc are not loaded

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(TaskDetails));
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: During debugging, could you hover over the `Frame` to see if the instance is the `DetailsFrame`? For example by checking the `Height` or similarly?

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `Navigate` line and then hover your mouse above `Frame` and check its properties

Comment: Did it, a value like Actual Heigh is 5000

Comment: What if you load the `TaskDetails` page in the main frame (not in the `DetailsFrame`. Do the controls appear?

Answer (score 0):

You should load `ProjectDetails` inside `DetailsFrame` and while moving to `TaskDetails` page, use:

```
DetailsFrame.Navigate(typeof(TaskDetails));
```

Instead of `Frame.Navigate(typeof(TaskDetails));`

Or create static instance of your detail frame and use it for navigation as below:

In your Main Page:

```
public static Frame NavigationFrame; 
public MainPage()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   NavigationFrame = DetailFrame;
}
```

And in the page where you want to perform navigation, use as below:

```
 MainPage.NavigationFrame.Navigate(typeof(SomeOtherPage));
```

Comment: Yea, but DetailsFrame is in another frame, how do I access that object? I tried with MainFrame.DetailsFrame but I can't access it

Comment: You can create static instance of DetailFrame and than can access it from other page, but the better solution is to implement some navigation service and inject your detail frame.

Comment: How do I create a static instance?

Comment: This should not be necessary when the page is already in the context of the `DetailsFrame`, the `Frame` will point to `DetailsFrame`

Comment: yea, but then I don't understand why the content of the page is not loaded on that frame

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why or how, but I solved the problem after messing around for a while, just deleting the page "TaskDetails" and creating a new one